# How to make localhost website visible to public , if the website is hosted on one of the machine of intranet .

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu-10.04, hosting

I have 25 machines in intranet and 1 of it is hosting a website . Website is accessible to every machine in intranet using the ip address . But how to make it visible to public ?

Comment: You need to tell us how your intranet is connected to the internet. Is it via a router, or does one of your machines have 2 network devices?

Comment: It is connected via router and rest of the machines through switches which is further connected to the same router .

Comment: Then you should be able to do it using the answer provided by @mauro.stettler below. Log in to the admin backend of your router and set up port forwarding.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you use some router with NAT to connect to the internet?

If that's the case, your router needs to do a port forwarding from the public IP address to the private IP address of this server that hosts the website. You need port 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS.

In case you want to point a public DNS name to your website, you will need to point it to the public IP of your router.

Comment: I made following changes in Router's Configuration - 
----------
Server Name  External Port Start  External Port End  Protocol  Internal Port Start  Internal Port End  Server IP Address  WAN Interface  Remove
------------
Web Server (HTTP)  80  80  TCP  80  80  192.168.1.14  ppp0  

I tried accessing using my Public Ip address but it isn't working . Any suggestions ?